# why sub dialog box is not coming inside main dialog in aikau

Tags: alfresco-share, aikau

I am newbie to aikau and working on some examples.Why dialog box  is not coming when i click button(ADD TAGS) inside main dialog box.

when i click Upload button ,main dialog box is coming.but inside another button exists which should call another dialog.but thats not happening.how to debug these issues?

```
model.jsonModel = {
      services: [
        "alfresco/services/ContentService",
        "alfresco/services/DialogService",
        "alfresco/services/DocumentService",

        "alfresco/services/NotificationService",
        "alfresco/services/CrudService"
      ],
      widgets: [
        {
          name: "alfresco/buttons/AlfButton",
          config: {
            label: "Upload",
            publishTopic: "ALF_CREATE_FORM_DIALOG_REQUEST",
            name: "targetData.destination",
            publishPayload: {
            dialogId: "UPLOAD_DIALOG",
            dialogTitle: "Upload a file",
            formSubmissionTopic: "ALF_UPLOAD_REQUEST",
            formSubmissionPayloadMixin: {
              targetData: {
                siteId: null,
                containerId: null
              }
            },
            widgets: [
                 {
                       name: "alfresco/forms/controls/TextBox",
                       config: {
                          fieldId: "Name",
                          name: "Name",
                          label: "Name",
                          placeHolder: "Name"

                       }
                    },

                    {
                           name: "alfresco/forms/controls/TextBox",
                           config: {
                              fieldId: "Description",
                              name: "Description",
                              label: "Description",
                              placeHolder: "Description"
                           }
                        },

                   {
                          name: "alfresco/buttons/AlfButton",
                          config: {
                            label: "Add Tags",
                            publishTopic: "ALF_CREATE_FORM_DIALOG_REQUEST",
                            publishPayload: {
                            dialogId: "ADD_TAGS",
                            dialogTitle: "Select.....",
                            formSubmissionTopic: "ALF_UPLOAD_REQUEST",
                            formSubmissionPayloadMixin: {
                              targetData: {
                                siteId: null,
                                containerId: null
                              }
                            },
                            widgets: [
                                        {
                                            name: "alfresco/forms/controls/SimplePicker",
                                            config: {
                                           label: "Pick Tags",
                                           description: "This is a simple picker publishes a request to get data to display",
                                           name: "Tags",
                                           loadDataPublishTopic: "ALF_CRUD_GET_ALL",
                                           loadDataPublishPayload: {
                                             url: "api/tags/workspace/SpacesStore?details=true&from=0&size=15"
                                           },
                                           itemsProperty: "data.items",
                                           itemKey: "name",
                                           propertyToRender: "name",
                                           availableItemsLabel: "Available Tags",
                                           pickedItemsLabel: "Currently Selected Tags"
                                        }

                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                          }
                   }

            ]
          }
        }
       }
     ]
    };
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it is not working :-(. When I click the 'Add Tags' button the event is not firing. Can you enable logs using debug option and see the difference?

Comment: I have enabled the debug option and did not get any clue.